Reledmac marginalnote overflow to next page
I am using the reledmac package and I have long side notes in my text, for which I use \ledsidenote. I used \rightnoteupfalse and \leftnoteupfalse, so that the first line of the side notes will be at the top, because I need the first line to be at the same height of the word the side note refers to. Now, if I have a long side note that goes below the lower margin of the page, I would like for it to continue on the next page, but this does not happen. The side note just disappears beyond the bottom of the page. So, is there a way to format the side notes, so that they continue on the next page? Thanks!
Answering to a comment I received, I add the following example:
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}


\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage [oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}


\usepackage[series={B,C,A,D},noend,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[C]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[D]{paragraph}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[B,C,A,D]
\Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines[B,C,A,D]
\Xsymlinenum[B,C,A,D]{|}
\Xnotenumfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\Xlemmadisablefontselection[]

\Xtxtbeforenotes[B]{\textbf{App. font. }}
\Xtxtbeforenotes[C]{\textbf{App. orth. }}
\Xtxtbeforenotes[A]{\textbf{App. marg. }}
\Xtxtbeforenotes[D]{\textbf{App. crit. }}

\sidenotemargin{outer}
\linenummargin{inner}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\center}{}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\huge\center}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\rightnoteupfalse 
\leftnoteupfalse

\pstart
\eledchapter*{Chapter Title}
\pend

\pstart
This is a sample text \edtext{text}{\Dfootnote{This is a sample apparatus}} This is a sample text This is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample text This is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample textThis is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text \ledsidenote{This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note This is a marginal note }This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text This is a sample text 
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}

This is the result (Ideally, I would like the sidenote to stop when the main text stops, before the critical apparatus, and continue on the next page, thanks!):


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you provide a minimal working example showing your problem?
